# Where should i put django application folder

Tags: django

I have followed several django tutorials on the web.
There is 2 folders: One for django project and another for application. We can have multiple applications for the same project but i my case, i have just one.

Sometimes, the application folder is located at the same level than project folder and sometimes, the application folder is located inside project folder.

I do not know what is the best solution... It works in both case. It is just a state of the art question

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Mostly it is a matter of choice and the organization of your Project. Even thought, i will post you here a recomented layout and good reasons to choose this

`myproject/
    manage.py
    myproject/
        __init__.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
        settings/
            __init__.py
            base.py
            dev.py
            prod.py
    blog/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        managers.py
        views.py
        urls.py
        templates/
            blog/
                base.html
                list.html
                detail.html
        static/
           …
        tests/
            __init__.py
            test_models.py
            test_managers.py
            test_views.py
    users/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        views.py
        urls.py
        templates/
            users/
                base.html
                list.html
                detail.html
        static/
            …
        tests/
            __init__.py
            test_models.py
            test_views.py
     static/
         css/
             …
         js/
             …
     templates/
         base.html
         index.html
     requirements/
         base.txt
         dev.txt
         test.txt
         prod.txt`

- Allows you to pick up, repackage, and reuse individual Django applications for use in other projects
- Environment specific settings. This allows to easily see which settings are shared and what is overridden on a per environment basis.
- Environment specific PIP requirements
- Environment specific PIP requirements
- Small more specific test files which are easier to read and understand.

Comment: Thanks. Can you confirm me that apps in django are the equivalent of symfony bundles ?